# MATLAB Symbolic coeffs issues

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I'm working with MATLAB's symbolic toolbox, and I'm having some issues pulling out the coefficients of derivatives.  Maybe MATLAB can't do what I am looking for.  Anyway, code that reproduces the issue I'm having is shown below:

```
clear ; close all; clc;
syms a b t
x = sym('x(t)');
y = sym('y(t)');
syms a b;

ra = a*cos(x);
radot = diff(ra, t);
xdot = diff(x,t);
ydot = diff(y,t);

% This one works as expected
works = coeffs(radot(1), xdot)
% This doesn't work as expected
fails = coeffs(radot(1), ydot)
```

Comments in the above code sections highlight what works and what does not work as expected.  Specifically, the outputs are:

```
radot =
-a*sin(x(t))*diff(x(t), t)
works =
-a*sin(x(t))
fails =
-a*sin(x(t))*diff(x(t), t)
```

Does anyone know why this happens or whether I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The result of the last line is constant with respect to `ydot`, and therefore the whole expression is seen as a single coefficient (a constant).

What is your expected result for `coeffs(radot(1), ydot)`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may be using `coeffs` for something that it wasn't meant for. Look at the help. It's designed to give the coefficients of a polynomial, not wether a differential equation is a function of one variable or another.

If you happen to be trying to take the derivative with respect to `xdot` and `ydot`, you can do this

```
syms z; % Subsitution variable for diff(x(t), t) and diff(y(t), t)
diff(subs(radot(1),xdot,z),z)
diff(subs(radot(1),ydot,z),z)
```

which returns

```
ans =

-a*sin(x(t))


ans = 

0
```